# Crossing the Black Sea (Ukraine to Georgia) by boat - risk of being boarded in a private vessel?

Tags: georgia-country, event-based-effects, ukraine, black-sea

I am planning to go from Ukraine to Georgia crossing the Black Sea, not by a ferry but using a private boat.

I would like to know if some people have experienced crossing Black Sea, and if it is reasonable to do his by now given the current military context and many cruisers and destroyers from US or Russia beeing there.

Also, is there a right or a possibility to get boarded by a military vessel from Russia (or other country), since Russia has now control of Crimea and because of the tensions, are they concretely making the police on the Black sea or is it still international waters and they have no right to do anything.

Comment: As far as I can see, US Navy presence in the Black Sea is not "many cruisers and destroyers" but at most a couple of ships.

Comment: it changes all the time, at some moment there was a significant presence of the US navy in he black sea and this may change at any moment because of the context.

Comment: By that reasoning, your question is completely unanswerable: anything anyone says could be invalidated at any moment by a change in the situation.

Comment: then considerating the worst case, eg that there 'are a lot of US war ships in the black sea'... anyway my main point was about Russian war ships

Comment: and why would the US Navy harass private vessels in international waters anyway, unless there's a prior suspicion that they're carrying fugitives from US justice (in which case the FBI sometimes asks their help in making an arrest)? The Red Navy yes, but they're more likely to do it in Ukrainian territorial waters (which they consider to be Russian territorial waters).

Comment: There is always a possibility that a military vessel might stop you - not much you can do about that other than hope and pray. Legally, most countries have jurisdiction from their shore up to 200 nautical miles (or the halfway point if that distance would overlap with that of another nation, as is likely the case in I would think all of the Black Sea basically).

Answer (score 5):

Despite the picture you may get from the media, the area is quite safe. My mother lives in Crimea and I visit her every once in a while. Life didn't change much after the peninsula changed flags.

A few things to keep in mind are the laws of Ukraine and Georgia:

- You will be refused to enter Ukraine by land from Crimea if you don't hold a Ukrainian passport or special permission from Ukrainian authorities
- You will be generally refused to enter Georgia by land from Abkhazia

Answer (score 1):

> if it is reasonable to do his

I'm afraid we don't know what 'reasonable' means for you.

If you want a safe trip but anyway by sea then I'd suggest start from Odessa (or sea ports nearby) and Turkey (at least Turkey's water) as an intermediate point.

And usually it is not possible to travel by a military vessel.

Comment: I am well aware of ferries and mix cargo from illichievtsk to poti and batumi.. for some reasons, I will be crossing the black sea with a private ship and a captain that I will hire for money. reasonable means: not been arrested or worst by a war ship. What should I do to maximize my chances of reaching batumi safely ?

Comment: @KarlZorn I didn't mention you should use regular traffic ;) I'd use the same route if I'm on a private ship. Just keep as far as possible away from area controlled by Russians.

Comment: It'd be great to have an explanation of 'minuses'